# Facebook graph API: Filter status from feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use 
`http://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed?access_token=MY_APP_TOKEN`
This works but I would like to exclude the status updates from the result and only get links,photos and videos. There seems to be a filter function as listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/feed
But I don't get how to use it :-(

...cocacola is just an example of course...

Answer (score 0):

I also couldn't get it to work with the Graph API itself, because the docs lack (**again**) details on how to use it.

You can use FQL to achieve what you desire instead:

```
select post_id, message, attachment from stream where source_id=me() and type in (80,128,247) limit 50
```

This will return your 50 most recently posted links, videos and photos. Remember that you'll need `read_stream` permissions if you access user info. For public page posts, this should be fine without.

Try it: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=select%20post_id%2C%20message%2C%20attachment%20from%20stream%20where%20source_id%3Dme()%20and%20type%20in%20(80%2C128%2C247)%20limit%2050%0A%0A

To change the subject of the query, change the `source_id` object_id. For CocaCola, this would be **40796308305** (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=cocacola%3Ffields%3Did&version=v2.0).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I know about fql, but the support of the fql api is deprecated. The result of the graph API also contains much more information which aren't avaible using fql querys (for example author name of comments and likes). Of course I could filter the result in my application, but this will make pagination a mess. Is there absolutely no way to add such a filter to the graph api?

Comment: FQL will be around 2 years AFTER the next version of the Graph API is introduced. I'd say this is plenty of time to still use it. And, who knows what happens to Graph API upon the next release

Comment: Using a deprecated code, which may be even supported N months/years is an extremely bad approach :)

Comment: @ecdeveloper It's perfectly documented when FQL will be out of duty. It's August 7th 2016. So I don't see your point. I even said that in my last comment (from July 2014!). If someone's got a v2.0 app, he'll be able to use FQL until then. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions#howlong and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_1 Get your facts right please.

Comment: @Tobi My point is that any deprecated code usage should be avoided. This is a good practice, IMO.

Comment: @ecdeveloper Sure, everybody would agree to that. Still, I repeat myself again, if somebody has a Graph API v2.0 app he can still use FQL for more tha two years. So, how much sense would it make to stop using it now if there's currently no alternative? Just because you deem it as "bad pratice"?

Comment: @Tobi Here is what Facebook says about it - "Please migrate your applications to use Graph API instead of FQL. Please see our changelog for current version information". It's up to developer to use it or not, though.

Comment: @ecdeveloper You cannot migrate from FQL if the current Graph API doesn't provide the funtionality. Whatever. I stop here now.